# C# decoding "â„¢" to "TM"

Tags: c#, encoding, decoding

on a web page there is following string

"Qualcomm Snapdragon™ S4"

when i get this string in my .net code the string convert to "Qualcomm Snapdragonâ„¢ S4"

the character "TM" change to â„¢

how can i decode "â„¢" back to "TM"

Update

follwoing is the code for downloaded string using webproxy
wc is webproxy

```
wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8");
string html = Server.HtmlEncode(wc.DownloadString(url));
```

Comment: How do you get that ".net code"? Seems like something went wrong.

Comment: @Henk Holterman...actually the string is comming from decoded html text....

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400002/fix-special-characters-in-string

Comment: @AbdulBasit - the error is proably in _how_ you decode it... So this is unanswerable.

Comment: Show the code where you fetch the web page and create your .NET string. Somewhere you need to give an `Encoding.UTF8` because that is the encoding the web page uses. Or even better notice what encoding the web server claims to be using and respect that encoding.

Comment: Then try `wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;` before `wc.DownloadString`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read the webpage in its proper encoding in the first place. In this case it seems you are reading with `Encoding.Default` (i.e. probably CP1252) and the page is really in UTF-8. This should be apparent either by reading the `Content-Type` header of the response or by looking for a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>` in the content.

If you still need to do this after the fact, then use

```
var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(myString);
var correctString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

In any case you would need to know the exact encodings that were used on the page *and* for reading the malformed string in the first place. Furthermore I'd generally advise explicitly against using `Encoding.Default` because its value isn't fixed. It's just the legacy encoding on a Windows system for use in non-Unicode applications and also gets used as the default non-Unicode text file encoding. It should have no place whatsoever in handling external resources.

Comment: This is what i have done. can u help me what is wrong in this code.....
wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8");
string html = Server.HtmlEncode(wc.DownloadString(url));

Comment: `Accept-Charset` is only a hint to the server, it has no obligation to honour it. Although in this case it clearly did by sending UTF-8 which you said was acceptable. However, `DownloadString` should use the encoding specified in the response to decode the body. So apparently the server is not sending anything or the wrong value there (sadly very common). In this case if you know it's UTF-8 you can just use `DownloadData` instead and decode it to a string yourself.

Comment: Also see my comment to the question. There is `wc.Encoding` property which can be set. Probably the web server regards UTF-8 as a standard encoding that it feels it doesn't have to declare.

Comment: @Jeppe, it can also happen that the response doesn't declare an encoding and instead the HTML does. But that's something that `WebClient` won't pick up.